# ag-grid-vue subscribe to event programmatically

Tags: typescript, event-handling, ag-grid-vue

I'm trying to subscribe to Ag-Grid from Vue directive

```js
function insert(el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding, {componentInstance} : VNode){
    
    let grid = componentInstance as AgGridVue;

    grid.$on('rowDataChanged', (params) => {
      console.log(params) //Doesn't even enter to this event
    })

    grid.$on('row-data-changed', (params) => {
      console.log(params) //Neither here
    })
    
}
```

I just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the needle in the haystack with debugging

```js
let events = (componentInstance as any).gridOptions.api.eventService as EventService;

events.addEventListener('cellValueChanged', function (evt: CellValueChangedEvent) {
    // Logic
})
```